# my texture turn to solid color when rendering. Looks ok in material mode. All other textures on the model look good just one surface

Tags: texturing

[image]I have unwrapped it several times. replace the nodes and textures. I was trying to do a bake of the outside walls when this started to happen.[image]

Comment: Please add a better image of your node setup, the current one is not readable.

Comment: Ok How do I add another picture?

Comment: did you UV unwrap the object?

Comment: yes a few times

Comment: @steveU You probably lack the reputation, link it in the comments, we will add it for you

Comment: node set up 2018-03-18 at 8.05.34 PM.jpg

Comment: Well pasting a file name will not suffice. Use the upload image button then paste the provided link here

Comment: Sorry first time here. Not sure where the upload image button is.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out ! There was a old baked UV map under the object data tap. I had made it when trying to bake textures for the walls. Deleted it and all is well.

Comment: Found similar issue when exporting to gltf / glb at times.